# jqGrid not showing table

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to show a table with jqGrid.
Can someone explain me why this is not working? I I can't see any table and I don't get any javascript error!
You can copy and paste this code in an html file and it should work (once the problem is solved)

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html width="100%" height="100%">
<head>
    <title>payments search</title>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www2.test.org.uk/OpenSocialSamples/visualiser.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
                {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
                {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
                {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
            ],
            multiselect: true,
            caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
        });
        var mydata = [
            {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];
        for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
            jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
    </script>
</head>
<body width="100%" height="100%" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0.5em;">
    <table id="list4"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code. The main problems are that you don't include any CSS files which really needed and don't use `jQuery(document).ready(function () {/*you code here*/});` construct to wait till the document is loaded. To write less words I fixed all problems and change the code to use `data` parameter instead of less effective `addRowData`.

You can see the fixed example live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Lince81.htm).